# Category products not found

Tags: magento-1.9, rajawali

> WHOOPS, OUR BAD...   The page you requested was not found, and we have
>   a fine guess why.   If you typed the URL directly, please make sure
>   the spelling is correct.   If you clicked on a link to get here, the
>   link is outdated.
>
> What can you do?
>
> Have no fear, help is near! There are many ways you can get back on
>   track with Magento Store.
>
> Go back to the previous page.
>
> Use the search bar at the top of the page to search for your products.
>
> Follow these links to get you back on track!
>
> Store Home | My Account.

I get these errors in Magento. How should I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You might have faced problem due to following reasons.

1. Your category is not active in admin
2. If active, products are not assigned.
3. If assigned, Indexing is not done.
4. If indexing done, please ensure you are using default category URL.
5. If category url is not default, please make sure you did catalog_url_rewrite indexing properly.

These above are the cases where you can get resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the 'url rewrite' that created urls are correct, specifically in the column 'url requested' because sometimes puts extensions like 'htm, html ...) or perhaps have some special character.